# JavaScript: how to filter a string array based on a boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a newbie to JavaScript, and now trying to find a way to filter a string array based on a boolean array.

Given

```
arr1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
arr2 = [false, true, false]
```

The expected output is:

```
["Banana"]
```

I tried

```
arr1.filter(item => arr2[item])
```

but it didn't work. Could you please figure out where I was wrong and what could be a better solution. Your answers will be highly appreicated.

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212). The [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) immediately reveals what `item` is and `console.log(arr2[item])` would immediately reveal why this doesn’t work. And the linked question can be found by [literally typing your exact title into Google](//google.com/search?q=JavaScript%3A+how+to+filter+a+string+array+based+on+a+boolean+array) (second result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index in `filter()`,then check the value in `arr2`

[image]

```js
let arr1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
let arr2 = [false, true, false]

let result = arr1.filter((e,i) => arr2[i])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, which really helps me a lot. May I ask what kind of role "e" play here since it has not been used?

Comment: @WenMa `e` is the iterate element and `i` is the iterate element index,see the picture or official document,you will find it